# How to force two inline elements wrap together

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following problem: This is the html:

```
<div>
    <a href="x">Link text can also be long</a>
    <button class="xx"></button>
</div>
```

I want that the two elements in div (a and button) positioning themselves always next to eachother.

At the moment, when i change the window size and there is not enough space for both elements, button is wrapped, a is in 1. line, button in 2.
What i want is, a part of text (tag a) can also pre-wrap with the button, so the button is never alone in 2. line.

How can i do that? I have been playing around with white-space:nowrap.. but no success yet.

Edit: using display flex on div:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

What i don't want:

[image]

Comment: but then the button stands always next to 2-3-x lines of text.. I would like  to have the button exactly at the end of text. For example it should also be staying directly under the 1. text line. Edit: I edited the question

Comment: @akcasoy Can you create fiddle?

Comment: add flex-wrap: wrap and justify-content: space-around to the div

Comment: @vishugosain nope. does not make also sense

Comment: @NoOorZ24 strange to ask a fiddle for this.. but here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/e6md27n0/   You have to change your browser size to see the problem

Comment: jsfiddle working fine according to your need

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pure *CSS* if you change the structure a little bit and *wrap* the last *hyperlinked* word with the `button`, and `display` the *wrapper* *element* as `inline-block`:

```css
button {border-radius: 50%}

div {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation: width 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

.common {display: inline-block}

@keyframes width {
  to {width: 100px}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="x">Yes this is a very long text but it </a>
  <span class="common"><a href="x">helps</a> <button class="xx">i</button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```css
a span{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="x">Link text can also be <span>long <button class="xx">i</button></span></a>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it.. this is an angular app.. and the links may have different texts. So i do not know how long a text can be.. i cannot change the html structure much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with pure `css`,so must get help of `javascript`.

```css
.spanWrap { display: inline-block; }

a { text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="x">Link text can also be long Link text can also be Link text can also be long Link text can also be</a>
  <button class="xx">Button</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var copyStr = $('a[href=x]').text();
      var tempStr = copyStr.substring(0, copyStr.lastIndexOf(" "));
      var last_word_arr = copyStr.split(" ");
      var last_word = last_word_arr[last_word_arr.length - 1];
      $('a[href=x]').text(tempStr);
      $('.xx').wrap('<span class="spanWrap"><a href="x">' + last_word +' </a></span>');
    })    
  </script>
</div>
```

**Note:** resize browser and see result.